# Dynamically allocate enough memory on client and server receive part

Tags: c, sockets

I wish to dynamically allocate enough memory on the server and clients receive part when I send a package. I.e. if I send a package of 512 bytes to client from server, I want the clients sides `char* receive_data` to allocate corresponding amount of memory of the package.

Here's some pseudo code:
I was thinking of having an counter which loops 2 times, on the first loop it'll send the client/server the length of the package and on the second run it'll send the package itself.

```
int write_all(int socket, void *buffer, size_t *length){

int ret;
int counter = 0;

while (counter != 2) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        // Write() the length to client/server.
    } else {
        ret = write(socket, buffer, length);
        if(ret < 1) break;
    }

    counter++;
}
return ret == -1 ? -1 : 0;
```

Is this a good or bad way to do this? I might have tunnel vision, if you have a more suitable way of doing this, please share.

Edit: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#sendall  I've read this part, and thought that perhaps be another way to do it. But then I have to statically allocate a char
(`char receive_data[512];`). Which might work as well, but is it as flexible as the way I'm trying to do it?

Comment: Don't forget that TCP sockets are streams of bytes without message boundaries. The network can chop/fragment/reassemble IP packets. So a single `send` is never guaranteed to correspond to one `recv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: This first part of the answer deals with the suitability of alternatingly sending message size and message proper as a communication protocol*

It will work, unless you can get out of sync. (I.e. could the receiver possibly miss the size packet but receive the data packet?)

You should also consider security implications: Can an attacker cause a denial of service by sending you an absurdly large data size, causing your server process to either swap massively or die.

Usually your problem is addressed by logically splitting network packets into a header and a body part, and some field in the header specifies the packet length. And the maximum length is limited to a reasonable value. This is very similar with what you do.

*Edit: This second part of the answer deals with short reads/writes*

After reading your latest comment, I guess your problem is:

Your communication is over TCP. This is your first time you do something like this. You've read about short reads and short writes, i.e. read() reading fewer bytes than you told it to, or write writing fewer bytes than you had available. You've read about how people usually deal with this (bookkeeping), but you wonder if there might be an easier solution: What if you just allocated enough memory, so that there would be no need for the read and write system calls to return without reading/writing everything you told them to.

Is that about about correct?

Then my response is: No, this is not a valid solution for the short read / short write problem. The limiting factor is not the memory that you provide to these system calls. All of your reads and writes may still end up shorter than you told them to. There is no easy way out of the bookkeeping.

Comment: If you may read my edit. Would you go for the first suggestion or the one i edited?

Comment: @ServO: Ok, but the description that you link to describes how to cope with short writes, which is something that you need to do when sending over TCP, but is orthogonal to the problem of allocating enough memory on the receiver side, which your question is about. You do not have a choice of doing one or the other, you need to do both.

Comment: Hmm yeah, have hard time processing that. As of the first example I though I simply could find the length send and manage the length of the data on i.e client side, to allocate enough memory, so I can send the whole package in one go. But as for the link i send, I believe the client part has a prefixed array size of 512, and the data is constantly written untill the package has been delivered. Say the package is 1024, that means I have to loop 2 times to send the package.

Comment: On the receiving side it's best to assume the network is arbitrary and capricious. Write your code so it works properly even if `recv()` returns exactly one byte at a time. Write your code so it works properly even if `recv()` coalesces multiple `send()`s into a single buffer.

Comment: Yes like keithmo says. It's the same on the sending side - your code should still work even if write accepts only one byte at a time.

Comment: After excessive amount of programming, I made it. Thank you.